# Attendance table in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design

My web application stores attendance of employees daily..

- How to design an attendance table
  in sql server 2005?

I tried to figure it like this, Attendance table will contain columns **EmpId,MonthId,1,2,3,4.....31**..

- Is this ok enough to hold attendance?

Any suggestions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be of your interest.
[Storing attendance records in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998298/storing-attendance-records-in-the-database)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you need to query the database, that approach could be the most efficient. However, I'd probably use the columns **employee_id** of integer, **date** of datetime.

While there would be many more rows this way, I think it makes a lot more sense.