# Storing attendance in a database

Tags: database, oracle, jsp

I have 4 semester students and I am concerned about their attendances of each subject. Different semester students are grouped into batches. Each batch has an option to select a subject out of 36 subjects.

First I created a table, `subject`, where I have listed all the subjects of four batches with a subject code. I have another table `student` where I have `studentid` and 6 columns which will have the subject codes which are selected by a student. By performing a join I can know which subject a student has opted for.

Now I am not able to figure out how I can store daily attendances in a clean way. Please suggest a way because I need to store data of 365 days and more than 1500 students. (Sundays are not holidays for some batches).

I found few relevant topics including [Storing attendance records in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998298/storing-attendance-records-in-the-database) and a few others but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd have something like this:

```
Subjects( SubjectId PK, Name, etc... )
Classes( ClassId PK, SubjectId, DateTime periodBegin, etc... )
Students( StudentId PK, Name, etc... )
StudentAttendance( StudentId PK, ClassId PK )
```

`Subjects` contains a record for each subject, `Classes` contains a record for each scheduled class in the school calendar. The `Classes` table will need to be populated with actual class assemblies - you can either add them as they take place, or add them in a batch at the start of the academic year. The `Students` table is self-explanatory, and the `StudentAttendance` table lists which students were positively attending a specific class.

Do not think that a table like `StudentAttendance` is a bad design - this is a canonical example of a many-to-many join table. It is not unusual to see some databases that have billions of rows in join tables, but because it only contains two key values (presumably int32 or int64) it doesn't use much space on disk.

Here's a query that finds which students did not attend a specific class:

```
SELECT
    Name
FROM
    Students
WHERE
    StudentId NOT IN (
        SELECT
            StudentId
        FROM
            StudentAttendance
            INNER JOIN Classes ON StudentAttendance.ClassId = Classes.ClassId
        WHERE
            StudentAttendance.ClassId = @classId
    )
```

Here's a query that gets the attendance count for each student who attended a specific subject. Divide this by ( `SELECT Count(*) FROM Clases WHERE Classes.SubjectId = @subject` ) to get each student's attendance percentage. If a student never attended any class (deliberately or because they weren't registered for it) then they won't appear in the list.

```
SELECT
    Students.Name
    COUNT(*) As AttendanceCount
FROM
    StudentAttendance
    INNER JOIN Classes ON Classes.ClassId = StudentAttendance.ClassId
    INNER JOIN Students ON Students.StudentId = StudentAttendance.StudentId
GROUP BY
    StudentId
WHERE
    Classes.SubjectId = @subjectId
```

Comment: In my situation minimum 4 classes and max 6 classes held a day. So `studentAttendance` table will have 6*365 records per student and 6*365*1500 record total? Will it cause any performance issue? If I would like to store the date information too then what will be the best way to store it?

Comment: Thank you.. You just gave all the details which I would have tried to figure out after storing attendance. I am not used to the convention of `@subjectId` does it mean its a variable which I will embed in the program?

Comment: Assuming each `StudentAttandance` entry consumes 32 bytes (8 for `StudentId`, 8 for `ClassId`, and 16 for internal database use) and assuming 100% efficient packing in the database then given your estimations this database table will be no bigger than 3.2MB. You'll probably want to triple that to about 9MB if you add the necessary reverse-lookup indexes for the `ClassId` and `StudentId` columns - your RDBMS will manage those indexes so you don't need to worry about them.

Comment: `@subjectId` is a SQL parameter. My example SQL is in the T-SQL dialect which is used by MSSQL and Sybase. I understand you're using Oracle which uses the "PL/SQL" dialect which uses a different syntax for SQLparameters. You will need to research how to convert it into your dialect.

Comment: In oracle I use `&subjectId` as a SQL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a join table with foreign keys into both student and subject, as well as a date field, and store a row for each student attending a particular class on a given date.  With proper indexing, performance should be acceptable.