# Storing attendance data in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database

Bit of a carry on from this question here: [Database design for school attendance system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021580/database-design-for-school-attendance-system)

I am currently doing something similar but have a few additional questions. So the school has approx 200 students but this is constantly changing. They attend for roughly 200 days and its required to keep the attendance data for 7 years. This is my create table statement here:

```
CREATE TABLE attendance (
    studentID INTEGER REFERENCES students (studentID),
    date      DATE,
    present   BOOLEAN
);
```

My question is, is this the best way to create the table?

I haven't really done any direct database stuff from a UI before so my proposed solution was:

First a local variable that would use C# DateTime.Today function to get todays date;
Another local variable which would get the StudentID from the UI;
And then the attendance value which is a boolean, again set by the UI and stored as a 0/1;

All of these then combined into the Insert into SQL statement.

Is this the best way? Any tips or help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me! This scales nicely to hold as many days as you like, and it extends nicely if you wanted to add a new `attendance` attribute like `absence_reason` or something.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but the real test is - can you get the data you need out of it?

Comment: Are you sure you need the `present` column? Couldn't a lack of a row for a given student on a given day mean they're absent?

Comment: It looks like you've already got a working solution. Go head and try that out first and come back when you've encountered a problem (inefficiencies, scaling issues, etc). _You_ are the only person who knows your requirements, and most of the time you'll only know those requirements after you try out an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose this table instead:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentAttendance (
    StudentId int  NOT NULL REFERENCES Students (StudentId),
    Date      date NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY( StudentId, Date )
)
```

- I don't feel there is a need for a `present` column because the presence, or *lack of*, a row can indicate if a Student was present that day or not.
- The table has a **composite key** comprised of `StudentId + Date` - this means there cannot be duplicate records (i.e. only 1 row per student per day)
- "Id" is an abbreviation for `Identity`, it is not an initialism so it should not be all-uppercase (i.e. use `Id` instead of `ID`).

### Update

After having read the comments by other users, especially @JNevill, I recognise that you probably would want to store student absence reasons, which means you will need an `IsPresent bit` column (as a row could now mean an is-present or is-absent) with a `Notes nvarchar(max)` column, but we can extend this to a `tinyint` to store an enum value for different types of attendance records:

```
enum StudentAttendanceType
{
    Present = 0,
    UnauthorisedAbsence = 1,
    AuthorisedAbsence = 2,
    MedicalLeave = 3,
    // etc...
}

CREATE TABLE StudentAttendance (
    StudentId int           NOT NULL REFERENCES Students (StudentId),
    Date      date          NOT NULL,
    Type      tinyint       NOT NULL,
    Notes     nvarchar(max) NOT NULL

    PRIMARY KEY( StudentId, Date )
)
```